# Laravel block post request method

Tags: laravel

I create laravel api. but after setting headers still post method are not allowed.

[image]

my laravel middleware code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
  $headers = [
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding'
  ];

  if($request -> getMethod() == 'OPTIONS'){

    return response()->json('OK', 200, $headers );
  }
  $response = $next($request);
  foreach($headers as $key => $value){
    $response->header($key,$value);
  }
  return $response;
  }
```

Any idea what goes wrong?

**EDIT:**
i had route get instead of post... but after change it i got something like that:

[image]

Comment: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');`, the '*' doesn't work anymore with most of the browsers. you need to specify the domain allowed. check your console to see if that's the issue

Comment: can you show us your routes please

Answer (score 2):

You need to check your routes file. The fact that you are getting a 405 response and not a 404 means that the route has been registered but it is not accepting of POST requests. The most likely cause of this is that you have setup your route to receive GET requests.

As you haven't posted your routes I can't give you the complete code solution, but it would look something like changing the following from this:

```php
Route::get('/test22', 'Test22Controller@store');
```

to

```php
Route::post('/test22', 'Test22Controller@store');
```

Note the difference between the two is just using the `post` method instead of the `get` method.

**UPDATE**

The 419 response is down to the fact you are not sending a CSRF token. You can either exclude the route from CSRF verification by adding the route to the `except` property on the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware (not recommended).

**Or** you can send through the CSRF token in the request as a header. You can find out more information on how to do this in the [Laravel documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token).

Comment: You should not be using CSRF verification in an API

Comment: @N69S could you please explain why you should *not* be using CSRF verification in an API? This functionality in Laravel isn't designed specifically for Single Page Applications it is instead more for applications which are server-side-rendered but still make AJAX requests. A Restful API does not necessarily mean a Stateless API. You can still be making AJAX requests which uses the cookie in the browser for authentication rather than something like an access token or JWT token.

Comment: laravel uses api token, not CSRF

Comment: @GeorgeHanson REST is by definition stateless `Representational State Transfer`

Answer (score 1):

Check your routes. Seems like the route `/test22` with POST method doesn't exist.

You can verify by running artisan command as well to confirm.

```
php artisan route:list
```

In case you can verify that route exist, you can try to clear cache for the routes.

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: test22 exist xD  but method not xD just change it but next error occur

Comment: That is because you didn't send CSRF token. Add ```@csrf``` inside your form. That should work.

Comment: where exactly i have to insert csrf in laravel? in controller? becouse my route test22 are direct to controller and he generates output.   in axios i will have to set it in headre ye?

Comment: If you are using axios, yes set it in the header. Or you can send it as one of the parameter ```_token```.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your defined Routes to `api.php` where CSRF middleware in not involved which is logic since it's an API and by definition they need to be called from another domain/origin/ip

For the `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');`, your browser might prevent you from accepting the response of the request because the `*` (joker) is no longer supported by modern browser.

For that try

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
```

Or you can use [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

Comment: api can me at the same domain. Does not have to be seperate. Please dont give false information.

Comment: @NielsLucas if an API is at the same domain, it's no longer an API, but a `Stateful WebService`. Of course, you can mix-max at your convenience but that's not the standard

Comment: laravel uses an API midleware (api token), not web sessions. So it is stateless.

You can do the same with an own made API.